# Error while migrating from react-native-fcm to react-native-firebase

Tags: ios, typescript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am migrating my react native app that used react-native-fcm and react-native-firebase-analytics that are now deprecated to use react-native-firebase. 
The build runs fine, however when the app start, it stays on the splash screen for almost a minute (which is weird), then crashes with an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'RNFIR.requestPermissions()')
```

There is no such expression in my code, everything is up to date.
My guess is that it might come from inside the react-native-firebase lib but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no migration guide, I just uninstalled the deprecated packages and followed the installation instructions on http://rnfirebase.io

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove all the libraries installed from react-native-fcm in xcode, I migrated from react-native-fcm to react-native-firebase and there were a few left over libraries that I had to manually remove.